# GRUB2: установка на другой винт

Tags: linux, grub

Имеется рабочий Linux на /dev/sda, у него в качестве загрузчика GRUB2. Имеется второй винт - /dev/sdd с ext2-разделом /dev/sdd1. В /dev/sdd1/boot/linux лежит ядро. Никакого загрузчика на /dev/sdd нет, файлов кроме ядра на sdd1 тоже нет.

Хочу установить GRUB2 на /dev/sdd так, чтобы он в качестве ядра стартовал /dev/sdd1/boot/linux при загрузке с /dev/sdd. Как делать, да еще и так, чтобы не поломалась загрузка с /dev/sda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ужасно костыльный вариант, но в первом приближении заработало:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt
```

копируем в /mnt/boot содержимое /boot/grub

```
grub-install --boot-dir=/mnt/boot/ /dev/sdd
```

редактируем /mnt/grub/grub.cfg с указанием нужного файла ядра.

Answer (score 0):

физически отключаешь /dev/sda, запускаешь машину с единственным оставшимся диском, ставишь grub2 (с live cd например). Подключаешь отключенный диск обратно

Comment: А живую ось под это дело использовать нереально?

Comment: думаю, что в общем случае нет, так как разные BIOS могут по-разному идентифицировать sdd при выборе его как загрузочного. Но может повезти. Если жалко терять загрузчик на sda, лучше на период экспериментов его отключить

Comment: Хринова... Но вот, допустим, это будет та же машина, на которой работает живой линух с sda.

Comment: в принципе, через grub-install я могу установить загрузчик на /dev/sdd, но он будет использовать настройки системы с sda. Через rescue console я могу выбрать ядро и начать его загрузку. Но как сохранить изменения?

Comment: при изменении загрузочного диска меняется аппаратная конфигурация машины. Это не просто выбрать другое ядро; это ставить загрузчик на другое железо. Не выбрав предварительно sdd как загрузочный, загрузчик на него в общем случае не поставить. Надеюсь, я не очень запутанно изложил

Comment: Осилил ужасный костыль, см. ниже.